# Max count error Touch Key STM32

Tags: stm32, proximity-sensor

I am struggling with an STM32l053C8T6 microcontroller and testing touch/proximity in regard of size and shape of the electrodes.

I am using a Discovery 32L053C8 board. It has implemented support of capacitive sensing built in MCU. It also has example electrodes, which are working fine. Sensing is based on charge transfer principle.

Now, I am trying to do exact same configuration as in the example but with my own electrode. I assigned sampling capacitor to the one which is built in for the example and chose the channel from the same analog group of IOs (as described in documentation.)  I have added my own electrode. Pin configuration is PB2 electrode (Group 3 IO4) and PB1 sampling (Group 3 IO3, built in on the board). I have added piece of copper foil with a 1 kΩ resistor for ESD protection to pin 2.

Now I get *Max count error (maximum transfer charge cycles)* and I have no idea why. Can you help me?

Comment: Add a diagram of what you have connected, and your code.

Comment: The touch sensor works by counting the time it takes for the capacitor to charge to a given voltage.  If the capacitor is too big (or not connected right or the charging resistor is too big) then it will take too long to charge.  The timer counter overflows, and you get the given error message.